# Microsoft.TeamFoundation create project

Tags: c#, tfs

Here is some info about tfs sdk for TeamFoundation.

http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/18/tfs-2010-sdk-connecting-to-tfs-2010-programmaticallyndashpart-1.aspx

I'd like to create project within selected collection in TFS using my own script. Unfortunately I can't find any decent documentation :/ I've already managed to create Collection from .net script using instance of **ITeamProjectCollectionService** and method **QueueCreateCollection()**. I believe there is an option to create project as well somewhere in this SDK. Has any of you worked with this SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Powershell script to create a project according to our standards and it uses Team Foundation Server Powertools.

```
tfpt.exe createteamproject /collection:$collectionURL "/teamproject:$teamproject" /processtemplate:"Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013.2" /sourcecontrol:New /verbose /noportal
```

Note: Team Explorer must be installed on the same machine; its version must be equal or higher than TFS' version.

Sadly, there is no option to choose Git version control instead of TFVC.